# Rate of change of mass with respect to distance

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

I am having a bit of trouble with the following problem:

---

The position of a particle of unit mass is given by $R(t) = (t, t, t^2 - 2)$. The rate of change of mass of the particle $m$ with respect to the distance travelled by the particle $s$ at the position $(x, y, z)$ is given by $\frac{dm}{ds}(x, y, z) = y$. Compute the total change in the particle's mass between $t = 0$ and $t = 1$.

---

My initial approach was to first manipulate the given rate formula:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dm}{ds} &= y \\
\frac{dm}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} &= y\frac{ds}{dt} \\
\frac{dm}{dt} &= y\frac{ds}{dt}
\end{align*}
$$

but then to compute $\frac{ds}{dt}$, I sought to determine the formula for the distance travelled by the particle which is given by:

$$s = \int_0^1 \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2} dt$$

which I reckon would just give a constant value and would simply give $0$ when differentiated with respect to $t$.

I've hit a road block at this point. I'm sure integrating both sides of $\frac{dm}{dt} = y\frac{ds}{dt}$ with respect to $t$ will give the total change in mass, but the $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is posing a bit of an issue. What can/should I do from here?

Thank you!

Comment: Your integral is just a value $s(1)$, so it cannot be used to compute $\dot s$. The correct formula is $\dot s = \sqrt{\dot x^2 + \dot y^2 + \dot z^2}$

Comment: Thank you @blamocur, is there a reference for this? This is exactly what I'd been looking for but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Not sure about references, but if $\mathbf v(t)$ is location vector of you point with coordinates $(x(t), y(t), z(t)$, then its speed $\dot v$ has coordinates $(\dot x, \dot y, \dot z)$ and thus $\dot s = | \dot v| = \sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2}$

Comment: Note that $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$, etc so if you convert everything to $t$, the integral is not that bad.